# Vue Js where should I put generic functions

Tags: function, vue.js, architecture, vuejs2, helper

I have generic functions on my Vue JS (v. 2.5.17) project, but I don't know where should I placed them, there is any convention like in Rails helpers ? Or can I create a file anywhere and just import it where I needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for either [Plug-Ins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) or [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Use mixins if you want to add the same functionality for multiple components. Mixins basically add methods from the mixin to those of the component using it.

Use Plug-Ins to add global level functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If they are truly generic and unrelated to your view layer then you should probably write them in a separate file and import them where you need them. That's better in order to separate concerns. If they are related to your view layer then you can look into [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

I found [this article](https://itnext.io/anyway-heres-how-to-do-ajax-api-calls-with-vue-js-e71e57d5cf12) to be somewhat related to this issue and truly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the scale of your project or the generic functions you are writing there may be different ways to go about it. In my projects I use vuex, Vue's state management library where you can centralise all your globals and call them from anywhere in your project. Maybe the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) will help.